# accept() keeps returning 0

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, server

This is a simple server that merely accepts connections, then prints the socket descriptor. For some reason, whenever I run this the only socket descriptors I receive are of value 0. This even occurs with multiple clients connecting simultaneously. I seem to be misunderstanding something to do with the behavior of accept(), or there is some bug I cannot locate in my code. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

/* Utility for consisely killing the program. */
void abort_program(const char *error_message)
{
    fputs(error_message, stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Establishes a passive listening port, returns socket descriptor. */
int setup_passive_port(int port)
{
    struct protoent *ptrp;  // pointer to a protocol table entry
    struct sockaddr_in sad; // structure to hold server's address
    int     sd;             // socket descriptor for listening

    /* Map TCP transport protocol name to protocol number. */
    if (((long int) (ptrp = getprotobyname("tcp"))) == 0) 
        abort_program("ERROR: Cannot map TCP to protocol number\n");

    /* Create a socket. */
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, ptrp->p_proto);
    if (sd < 0) 
        abort_program("ERROR: Socket creation failed\n");

    /* Prepare the socket address structure. */
    memset((char *) &sad, 0, sizeof(sad));
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sad.sin_port = htons((u_short) port);

    /* Bind a local address to the socket. */
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0)
        abort_program("ERROR: Bind failed\n");

    /* Establish passive listener socket. */
    if (listen(sd, 0) < 0)
        abort_program("ERROR: Listen failed\n");    

    return sd;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in cad; // structure to hold client's address
    int     alen;           // length of address
    int     sd;             // incoming socket
    int     listener;       // listening socket

    listener = setup_passive_port(30000);

    while (1) {

        if (sd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*) &cad, &alen) < 0)
            abort_program("ERROR: Accept failed\n");

        printf("%d\n", sd);

    }

}
```

Can you help me understand why? Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Did you try to set the backlog parameter in listen to something like 1 or higher? Queues with 0 length are sometimes of limited fun...

Comment: 0 is a valid file discriptor for accept to return if it is not being used although very unlikely. Are you accepting more than one connection? is the listening socket in non-blocking mode. And is there a reson for listen queue being 0 can you increase it

Comment: Technically, your `socket()` call should specify the `domain` (first) argument as `AF_INET`, not `PF_INET`.  In practice, however, the two macros seem coincidentally to resolve to the same value in my environment.

Comment: I note, too, this excerpt from the Linux manpage for `socket()`: "Normally only a single protocol exists to support a particular socket type within a given protocol family, in which case `protocol` can be specified as 0."  I'd go so far as to say it is *routine* for the protocol to be specified as `0` unless there multiple applicable protocols (which is not the case for you).

Comment: At least if not using an ancient version of libc there is no need to cast here: `memset((char *) &sad, 0, sizeof(sad));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you need to do is to set your alen to the sizeof(sockaddr_in) prior to calling accept(). The other is that at least clang complains about the missing brackets within your if( accept()...) line. Here the fixed up version.

telnet localhost 30000 worked as expected.

Also changed your int alen to socklen_t alen while being at it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in cad; // structure to hold client's address
    socklen_t     alen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);           // length of address
    int     sd;             // incoming socket
    int     listener;       // listening socket

    listener = setup_passive_port(30000);

    while (1) {

        if ((sd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*) &cad, &alen)) < 0)
            abort_program("ERROR: Accept failed\n");

        printf("%d\n", sd);

    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, yes thank you. The problem was the parenthesization, where `sd` was being set to the result of `accept(...) < 0`. So sloppy of me. I appreciate your second set of eyes.

Comment: oh man. i wasted so much time because i never set `alen = sizeof(sockaddr)`. I just set it as undefined like: `socklen_t alen;`. Then my first client would always end up with some invalid ipv6 address like `::0`, but my subsequent returns from `accept()` would all work, since `alen` would be updated.

Comment: @spsteffl 5 years later, I have spent hours doing the exact thing you just described. Good Lord...

Who updates socklen_t and friends? I thought it was getaddrinfo() but man I was wrong...